Two different search sheets in 1 document seem to clash using VBA. How do I fix?
Currently I am trying to make a price list with a data entry form using the below code but keep getting this error. I do have in the same document a stock list which correlates very similarly would this affect anything?
Function validate() As Boolean

    Dim frm As Worksheet
    
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price List Data Entry Form")
    
    validate = True
    
    With frm
    
        .Range("I6").Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Range("I8").Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Range("I10").Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Range("I14").Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Range("I18").Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Range("I22").Interior.Color = xlNone
        .Range("I24").Interior.Color = xlNone
    End With
    
    'Validating Manufacturer
    
    If Trim(frm.Range("I6").Value) = "" Then
        frm.Range("I6").Select
        validate = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    
    'Validating Range
    
    If Trim(frm.Range("I8").Value) = "" Then
        frm.Range("I8").Select
        validate = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
     'Validating Product Colour/Code
    
    If Trim(frm.Range("I10").Value) = "" Then
        frm.Range("I10").Select
        validate = True
        Exit Function
    End If
            
     'Validating Length
    
    If Trim(frm.Range("I14").Value) = "" Then
        frm.Range("I14").Select
        validate = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
     'Validating Allocation Reference/Sold
    
    If Trim(frm.Range("I18").Value) = "" Then
        frm.Range("I18").Select
        validate = True
        Exit Function
    End If
 
     'Validating Pallet
     
     If Trim(frm.Range("I22").Value) = "" Then
        frm.Range("I22").Select
        validate = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    
     'Validating Rack
    
    If Trim(frm.Range("I24").Value) = "" Then
        frm.Range("I24").Select
        validate = True
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function

I've tried changing the "validate" to "validateprice" to try differentiate the difference between the stock list and the price list but it doesn't seem to work.

getting this error. ? What error ? Code compiles and runs OK for me.

The error might occur at frm.Range("I8").Select if the sheet is not the active sheet. Additionally, using a loop could help simplify your code.
Function validate() As Boolean

    Dim frm As Worksheet
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price List Data Entry Form")

    Const TARGET_CELLS = "I6,I8,I10,I14,I18,I22,I24"
    frm.Range(TARGET_CELLS).Interior.Color = xlNone
    validate = True
    'Validating 
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c in frm.Range(TARGET_CELLS).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = "" Then
            frm.Activate
            frm.Range("I6").Select
            validate = False  ' found blank
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function


You can use a loop, and flag every cell missing a value, instead of only highlighting the first cell missing an entry.  Better to tell your user up-front about all of the issues, instead of one-by-one.
Function IsValid() As Boolean
    Dim frm As Worksheet, rng As Range, c As Range
    
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Price List Data Entry Form")
    Set rng = frm.Range("I6,I8,I10,I14,I18,I22,I24")
    
    rng.Interior.Color = xlNone 'clear any fill
    
    IsValid = True 'default to OK
    
    'check each cell in `rng` has a value
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(Trim(c.Value)) = 0 Then
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            IsValid = False
        End If
    Next c
    
End Function

